ASP.NET : why is the dynamic delete button not working the first time?
I have a dynamically added delete button on my page, and it's working only after the second click, not on the first.
After the page is loaded, when I'm trying to delete a user on the first click, it doesn't respond at all, only after the second click.
I have tried many combinations with the page_load / display user, nothing works.
What is the reason?
This is my code behind:
public partial class UserPageDB : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static List<User> users;
    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            users = UserDao.GetUsersDB();
            // DisplayUsers();
        }

        // DisplayUsers();
        DisplayUsers();

        Debug.WriteLine("page_load");
    }
    
    private void DisplayUsers()
    {
        while (UsersTable.Rows.Count > 1) 
            UsersTable.Rows.RemoveAt(1);

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = user.GetUsername() });
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = user.GetPassword() });
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = user.GetFirstName() });
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = user.GetLastName() });
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = user.GetEmail() });
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = user.GetBirthday().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") });
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = user.GetCity() });
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = user.GetIsAdmin() ? "Admin" : "no Admin" });

            // Create the delete button
            Button deleteButton = new Button();
            deleteButton.Text = "X";
            deleteButton.CommandName = "Delete";
            deleteButton.CommandArgument = user.GetUsername(); // Pass username or other identifier
            deleteButton.Click += new EventHandler(DeleteUserDB); // Event handler
            deleteButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    
            // I create the TableCell for deleting user, and I add the button to it
            TableCell delete = new TableCell();
            delete.Controls.Add(deleteButton);
            row.Cells.Add(delete);

            UsersTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    
    protected void DeleteUserDB(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("deleting... ");

        UserDao.DeleteUser(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);
        ErrorMsg.Text = "User deleted successfully";
        ErrorMsg.Style.Add("Color", "Yellow");

        users = UserDao.GetUsersDB();
    
        DisplayUsers();
    }
}

ASPX page:
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="UsersTable" BorderWidth="1" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="10">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="Table1HeaderRow" BackColor="LightBlue" runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Username" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Password" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="First Name" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Last Name" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Email" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Birthday" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="City" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Role" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Delete" />
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>

<div class="addUserAdmin" runat="server">

